# AWS spot instances remove elastic ip address association when terminated

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-ip, spot-instances

I am new to ecs , I am able to run a cluster on spot instance and I can assign the Elastic ip address to this instance.

The problem is when the spot instance is terminated, it looses this association and my application goes down.

How can i auto attach my elastic ip to new created spot instances.

Comment: If instance that's terminated your application goes down anyway. EIP has nothing to do it.

Comment: The termination is not an issue , ecs issues new request for spot instances but this new instance is not attached to the elastic ip. Is there a way to modify the network config on ecs cluster configs

Comment: There is no such option. You need to develop your own solution for that. Probably some user data script would be enough.

Comment: With an ECS cluster, things should not be connecting to your instances directly. Access into the cluster should be restricted by a load balancer.

Comment: Might be relevant: [Amazon Route 53: How to automatically update IP addresses without using Elastic IPs - DEV Community](https://dev.to/aws/amazon-route-53-how-to-automatically-update-ip-addresses-without-using-elastic-ips-h7o)